# Using spot.im in AMP

Tags: accelerated-mobile-page, google-amp

I had implemented static web pages and I want to move them to AMP. I am using SPOT.IM (http://www.spot.im/) . Is there a way to use spot.im in AMP pages? or do you know of any different services to use for the same purpose in AMP pages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a way: https://github.com/SpotIM/spotim-integration-docs/blob/master/google-amp/README.md

You will have to use an amp-iframe component: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe

Add this script link to the head of your page:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
```

And use amp-iframe in the body of your page:

```
<amp-iframe width="375" height="815" resizable
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-top-navigation"
layout="responsive" frameborder="0"
src="https://amp.spot.im/production.html?spot_im_highlight_immediate=true&spotId=SPOT_ID&postId=POST_ID">
<amp-img placeholder height="815" layout="fill" src="//amp.spot.im/loader.png"></amp-img>
<div overflow class="spot-im-amp-overflow" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Read more">Load more...</div>
```

Use Your `SPOT_ID` and `POST_ID`